# How do I go about creating a user defined task multi threaded web application?

Tags: user-interface, web-applications

I want to create a web based application that is similar to the attached image. It is able to run as many "tasks" as the user wants to. Each "task" has its own email, size, link, and checkout profile defined by the user and the master log would display the status of each "task." What each task essentially does, is automate a purchase on a website using a different session and different details defined by the user. I am wondering how I should go about this. I know the basics to Java, Javascript, and python. I have basically recreated this program that is attached below in a simple python script, but I am stuck on creating the part with multiple tasks defined by the user. Any help is appreciated.
[Example Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhHvX.png)

Comment: Please post all relevant code and information in the question itself rather than simply linking to it.